# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "libman_classbooks" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I had mistakenly deleted my migration folders for all my apps in my project. I therefore had  to redo `makemigrations` and `migrate` for each of those apps. When thence I try to access the specific areas with relational paths I get an error.

```
relation "libman_classbooks" does not exist
```

When I try to make some changes on the models, save and try to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`. this does not go on well but returns.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "libman_classbooks" does not exist.
```

I have been forced to guess that I need to manually create the tables in the database. Using CREATETABLE. I don't know if this is the best option though.
So **I think** my option may be possible in development thro' the **pgAdmin,** but what about in production? If CREATETABLE is the best option to take, how will I do it for the production database??. I already have data in my database which do not need interference.

Comment: 1) Is the table name actually all lower case? 2) What schema is `libman_classbooks` in and is that schema in the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got this type issue [image: Created a Custom_user model but not able to make connection or getting issue when we are running command docker-compose]

Answer -

1. To resolve this issue, you have to comment `'django.contrib.admin'` this line in setting.py in installed app section, and then run command `docker exec -it <db-container name or ID> psql -U postgres` and check your database is exist or not if exist then Drop the DB and create new DB with same name.
2. After creating DB again run docker-compose up Now it will work and again uncomment the line which was commented in settings.py
3. Another approach In case if it is not working add this line in settings.py in installed app section `'app.apps.AppConfig'`then run docker- compose up it will work for you.